# NSLayoutAnchor and constraint identifier

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

If I were to use NSLayoutConstraint, I would first initialize the constraint, lets say:

```
let myConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(...)
```

Then I would add the identifier like that:

```
myConstraint.identifier = "myIdentifier"
```

Then I would activate:

```
myConstraint.active = true
```

Is there a way to add an identifier to a constraint that was created by using the `NSLayoutAnchor` class? I checked the documentation, however I did not find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. The apple docs say:

> The NSLayoutAnchor class is a factory class for creating NSLayoutConstraint objects using a fluent API. Use these constraints to programatically define your layout using Auto Layout.

So `NSLayoutAnchor` is just a class that creates constraints for you instances  of this class are not constraints.
An example:

```
subview.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.leadingAnchor).identifier = "myIdentifier"
```

Comment: However, as I see it, I cannot assign an identifier and activate the constraint in one line. I have to assign it to a constant (or variable) and then activate it, if I were to add an identifier.

Comment: That is still true when you use `NSLayoutConstraint `.